# Getting issue with sendbird application id in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am trying to authenticate user using sendbird iOS SDK.

Here is the syntax :

```
SBDMain.connect(withUserId: "123456", completionHandler: { (user, error) in

})
```

it gives me an error :

> Error Domain=Application ID not found. Code=800100 "(null)"

Error says application id is not configured properly but i have configured it correctly on `AppDelegate`. I don't understand why I'm getting this kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. (I don't know actual reason why it happen but this issue occur may be of old version)

**Do following Steps**

**1.** Replace Your `ApplicationID` with exist `ApplicationID` in `appDelegate`

**2.** In `PodFile` replace `pod 'SendBirdSDK', '~> 3.0'` with `pod 'SendBirdSDK'`

**3.** Update Demo Project `Pods`

**4.** Try to login with `123456`

Comment: Thanks for your help @kuldeep

Comment: @NityaEnterprise you welcome. If you don't mind than once you have enough reputation than accept this answer.